Seeking Assistance with NDepend CQLinq Query for Extracting Logical Class Groups from Monolith Codebase
I'm currently tasked with breaking down a monolithic codebase into more manageable components. One of the initial steps involves restructuring the code and resolving circular namespace dependencies. Additionally, we've identified certain patterns that allow us to extract logical class groups into separate assemblies.
Within our codebase, we have a significant number of classes grouped under various namespaces. However, due to the code's size, identifying related classes within a namespace that depend on each other exclusively can be challenging.
For instance, suppose we have a namespace "NamespaceX" containing classes A, B, and C that are interdependent, another set of classes M, N, Q, and P forming another group, and a third group consisting of classes Y and Z.
I need assistance in crafting a CQLinq query that, given a namespace as input, can identify and return groups of related classes that exclusively depend on each other within that namespace but do not rely on any other classes within the same namespace.
The desired output would be sets of classes that can be extracted as separate components, facilitating the decomposition of our monolithic codebase.
Thank you in advance for any guidance or assistance provided!
I was trying something like this but it does not work .
// Define the namespace you want to analyze
let targetNamespace = Application.Namespaces.WithName("YourNamespace")
// Find classes within the target namespace that are not used by any other class in the same namespace
let groups =
from t in targetNamespace.ChildTypes.Where(t => t.IsClass)
let dependencies =
targetNamespace.ChildTypes
.Where(c => c.IsClass && c != t)
.Where(c => c.Methods.Any(m => m.IsUsing(t)))
.Select(c => c.Name)
where dependencies.Any()
group t by dependencies into g
select g
// Transform the grouped data
let transformedGroups =
from g in groups
let classNames = string.Join(", ", g.Select(t => t.Name))
let fileNames = string.Join(", ", g.Select(t => t.FullName))
select new {
DependentClasses = classNames,
FileNames = fileNames
}
// Execute the query
let result = transformedGroups.ToList()
// Return the result
select result
